# Generate Embarcadero project files from CMake files

Tags: c++, cmake, c++builder

I have a C++ code base with a large number of projects. Usually I can use CMake to generate the required project files for QtCreator, XCode, Visual Studio, etc. Now I need to compile for Embarcadero, but it does not seem that CMake supports it.

Does CMake support Embarcadero? If not, is there maybe some set of projects that I could generate with CMake and then import into Embarcadero.

Answer (score 1):

[For a toy example it may work with the bcc and bcc32c, bcc64 is not supported at all.](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-cmake-with-the-free-embarcadero-c-compiler)

Maybe the new "free" compiler will help to change that - the [press release](http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20160714005792/en/Embarcadero-Releases-Free-Compiler-Windows) seems to imply this.

Personally, I would not put my hopes to high. So far, everything I have seen from the company Embarcadero was just a let down.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMake's "Borland Makefiles" generator and then use Embarcadero's clang based bcc32c to compile the project. Here's their blog post about it: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-cmake-with-the-free-embarcadero-c-compiler

I didn't find a way to generate project files for their IDE yet, but I'm wondering if one could use one of the "Visual Studio" generators, then manually change the file extension (considering Embarcadero is using MSBuild). But that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current [CMake documentation on generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/manual/cmake-generators.7.html), no CMake does not produce Embarcadero project files. Instead, you could use one of the Makefile generators, and set your IDE to run `cmake` and `make` when you execute its "build" command.